# Retrieving result of Gulp 4 task programmatically

Tags: gulp

I am looking for a good way to run Gulp 4 programmatically, instead of just executing tasks with the command line. Furthermore, I would like to be able to retrieve the results of Gulp tasks. I am not sure if Gulp is particularly made for this, but I am going to try.

Gulp 3 tasks seem to return event emitters (or streams), not promises.

So I have this:

```
//start

    const gulp = module.exports = require('gulp');


    gulp.task('one', function(){
         return 5;
    });

    gulp.start('one').on('done', function(val){
       console.log('val => ', val);   //this doesn't work, maybe 'done' is not the right event to listen for 
    }).on('error', function(e){
      console.error(e.stack || e);  
    });

 //end
```

But what event can I listen to capture the returned/called back result of the Gulp task?

Comment: As far as I understand it, you are not supposed to use gulp for running a task programmatically, and `gulp.start` is not even part of the public API. The returned event emitter is the gulp object itself, but that would be an implementation detail, as far as it is concerned.

Comment: Yeah I agree that I do not thing Gulp 3 / Gulp 4 is intended for programmatic usage